# How to get a value of particular column from the object variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

From the model TagModel i can filter the value which i want it, but value is stored in the form of object variable. To play with those data in controller i am not able to pluck the particular id. 
This is my model

```
public static function getLatestTag($name){
    return $tagIds =DB::table('tags')
                    ->where ('is_deleted',0)
                    ->where('name',$name)
                    ->get();
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
foreach ($newTags as $newTag) {
                $productTagIds[] = TagModel::getLatestTag($newTag);
                dd($id);
            }

            $productId = (int)ProductManagementModel::getMaxId();
            foreach ($productTagIds as $productTagId) {
            $productTag = new ProductTagModel;
            $productTag ->product_id = $productId;
            $productTag ->tag_id = $productTagId;
            $productTag->save();    
            }
```

the value which i want is stored in the variable **$productTagIds** which is object variable. How can I pluck just id from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function addProduct()
    {       
            foreach(Input::get('tagName') as $checkTag){

                $newTags[]=$checkTag;
            }
            foreach ($newTags as $newTag) {
                if(TagModel::checkExist($newTag)){
                    $tagExist[] =  TagModel::checkExist($newTag);
                    $message = 'The tag <b>'.$checkTag.'</b>  already exist';
                Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
                Session::flash('message', $message);    
                return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                }
                else {  

                        $objectTagProduct = new TagModel;
                        $objectTagProduct ->name = $newTag;
                        $objectTagProduct->save();
                        $productTagIds[]=$objectTagProduct->id;

                }
            }
                $objectProduct = new ProductManagementModel;
                $objectProduct->product_name        = Input::get('product_name');
                $objectProduct->product_url         = $productUrl;
                $objectProduct->category_id         = Input::get('category_id');
                $objectProduct->product_cost        = Input::get('product_cost');
                $objectProduct->product_short_description = Input::get('product_short_description');
                $objectProduct->product_description = Input::get('product_description');
                $objectProduct->is_active   = Input::get('is_active');
                $objectProduct->created_at  = Auth::user()->id;
                $objectProduct->updated_at  = Auth::user()->id;

                if($logo != '')
                {
                $objectProduct->product_attachment = $logo; 
                }

                $objectProduct->save();

                $productId = (int)ProductManagementModel::getMaxId();
                //dd($productId);
                foreach ($productTagIds as $productTagId) {
                    //dd($productTagIds);
                $productTag = new ProductTagModel;
                $productTag ->product_id = $productId;
                $productTag ->tag_id = $productTagId;

                $productTag->save();    
                }


                if($objectProduct->id) {
                    Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-success');
                    Session::flash('message', 'Product successfully added');
                    return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                } else {
                    Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
                    Session::flash('message', 'Something error');
                    return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                }


    }
```

The code might flash a certain error that have to troubleshoot by yourself. I have kept
`$productTagIds[]=$objectTagProduct->id;`
after   `$objectTagProduct->save();` please try it

Comment: I am adding more information in the form of another answer.

Comment: It worked it. Thanks. I got the flow of object class variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getLatestTag($name){
    return $tagIds = DB::table('tags')
                    ->where ('is_deleted',0)
                    ->where('name',$name)
                    ->pluck(id);
}
```

Comment: Using  ->pluck('id') returns only one value. I passed multiple value that have to returns multiple ids of the name. It only returns the ids of first name.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getLatestTag($name){
    return App\TagModel::where('is_deleted',0)->where('name',$name)->first()->id;
}

$ids = [];
foreach ($newTags as $newTag) {
   $productTagId = TagModel::getLatestTag($newTag);
   array_push($ids,$productTagId);
}
 $productId = (int)ProductManagementModel::getMaxId();
 foreach ($ids as $productTagId) {
    $productTag = new ProductTagModel;
    $productTag ->product_id = $productId;
    $productTag ->tag_id = $productTagId;
    $productTag->save();    
 }
```

try to use eloquent like this

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

to get the particular value from the object class variable

```
$productTagIds[]=$objectTagProduct->id;`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addProduct()
    {       
            foreach(Input::get('tagName') as $checkTag){

                $newTags[]=$checkTag;
            }
            foreach ($newTags as $newTag) {
                if(TagModel::checkExist($newTag)){
                    $tagExist[] =  TagModel::checkExist($newTag);
                    $message = 'The tag <b>'.$checkTag.'</b>  already exist';
                Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
                Session::flash('message', $message);    
                return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                }
                else {  

                        $objectTagProduct = new TagModel;
                        $objectTagProduct ->name = $newTag;
                        $objectTagProduct->save();

                }
            }
                $objectProduct = new ProductManagementModel;
                $objectProduct->product_name        = Input::get('product_name');
                $objectProduct->product_url         = $productUrl;
                $objectProduct->category_id         = Input::get('category_id');
                $objectProduct->product_cost        = Input::get('product_cost');
                $objectProduct->product_short_description = Input::get('product_short_description');
                $objectProduct->product_description = Input::get('product_description');
                $objectProduct->is_active   = Input::get('is_active');
                $objectProduct->created_at  = Auth::user()->id;
                $objectProduct->updated_at  = Auth::user()->id;

                if($logo != '')
                {
                $objectProduct->product_attachment = $logo; 
                }

                $objectProduct->save();

                $productId = (int)ProductManagementModel::getMaxId();
                //dd($productId);
                foreach ($productTagIds as $productTagId) {
                    //dd($productTagIds);
                $productTag = new ProductTagModel;
                $productTag ->product_id = $productId;
                $productTag ->tag_id = $productTagId;
                $productTagIds[]=$objectTagProduct->id;
                $productTag->save();    
                }


                if($objectProduct->id) {
                    Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-success');
                    Session::flash('message', 'Product successfully added');
                    return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                } else {
                    Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
                    Session::flash('message', 'Something error');
                    return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                }


    }
```

I came to knew that to get the data from object class variable `$productTagIds[]=$objectTagProduct->id;`
 
But i am confused with its flow and where to execute this code.